# Guardar el option seleccionado a una variable con onchange=""

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy iniciandome en javascript y básicamente busco que al darle click a un option tome el valor y lo almacene en una variable de javascript(porque pensaba usarla para llenar otro select) pero probando me devuelve undefined. Igual me serviría mas pase directamente del select a almacenarse en una variable ya que lo puse a un p solo para ver su funcionamiento. Gracias por cualquier ayuda.

```
<html>
  <body>

     <p>Select a new car from the list.</p>

     <select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
       <option value="Audi">Audi
       <option value="BMW">BMW
       <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes
       <option value="Volvo">Volvo
     </select>



   <p id="demo"></p>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
   }
 </script>

 <script>
    var bbsita = document.getElementById("demo").value;
    window.alert(bbsita);//Quiero guarde el valor de demo para usarlo en otra funcion pero sale undefined al iniciar la ejecucion
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dandole vueltas al asunto me di cuenta que con el mismo codigo podia enviar el dato de demo y asignarlo a una variable js y dejandolo dentro de la funcion ya no devolvera indefinido

```
  <p>Select a new car from the list.</p>

 <select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
   <option value="Audi">Audi
   <option value="BMW">BMW
   <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes
   <option value="Volvo">Volvo
 </select>


  <p id="demo"></p> <!--Se puede remplazar por un input hidden y ocultarlo del html-->
```

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
 var alerta = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
 window.alert(alerta);//El valor de alerta se convierte en lo que el se selecciono en el select anterior
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Se utiliza `value` para los elementos  `<input>` de un  `<form>` en este caso demo es un elemento `<p>` de html por lo que se tiene que utilizar `text`

```
<html>
  <body>

     <p>Select a new car from the list.</p>

     <select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
       <option value="Audi">Audi
       <option value="BMW">BMW
       <option value="Mercedes">Mercedes
       <option value="Volvo">Volvo
     </select>



   <p id="demo"></p>

  <script>

    function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
   }

    var bbsita = document.getElementById("demo").text;
    window.alert(bbsita);//Quiero guarde el valor de demo para usarlo en otra funcion pero sale undefined al iniciar la ejecucion
</script>
 </body>
</html>
```